# XMLWriter in PHP writes full source code to the file

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, xmlwriter, writer

I am trying to create a code that extracts some information from my WordPress SQL database into an XML file.

I have an admin panel menu in my WordPress page with a button which initiates the code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('', '', '', ''); (with my database details)
    $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_2_postmeta ORDER BY post_id";
    $res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    header("Content-Type: text/html/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=adatszolgaltatas.xml");

    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI("php://output");
    $xml->setIndent(true);
    $xml->setIndentString("    ");  
    $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

    $xml->startElement('post_ids');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $xml->startElement("post_id");

    $xml->writeAttribute('post_id', $row['post_id']);
    $xml->writeRaw($row['post_id']);

    $xml->endElement();
    }

    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $xml->flush();
    unset($xml);
}
```

The output will be a saved .xml file. The problem is that it doesn't only consists of the needed data, but before and after the output lines there is also the full source code of the page that I have submitted it from.

What could cause an issue like this? How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around the problem by creating a file and saving the XMLWriter output to that file on the server and then force downloading it to the user before deleting it. This way the output .xml was correct.